# HTTP Error -5 occured when trying to download Views (WAMP)

Tags: http, drupal7

Can anyone explain to me what HTTP error -5 is? I get this error message every time I try to update or download a module in my Drupal 7 site locally. For example:

```
HTTP error -5 occurred when trying to fetch https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16.tar.gz.
```

The above is a translation from this screen after trying to download a module:[image]

There is nothing related to this error in the Apache or PHP error logs. Neither in the Drupal recent log messages or status messages.

Also it works fine to use command line tools to do the same thing, such as Drush or Git. There are no other problems with the computers internet connection. It's only when downloading modules from within the Drupal site UI, that this happens.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I also met the issue for drupal 7 on php 7. 
Finally after I enabled the openssl module for php, the install module from url works.

Comment: Upvote! Your answer put me on the right track. I don't use that module and I don't use php 7, but I enabled the php_openssl extension in my wampserver settings and then it worked! Thank you very much.